# Huawei IAP error in Flutter - Integrate the version update API (checkUpdate)

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-iap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDDUH.png)Integrate the version update API (checkUpdate). If you already integrate the API, check whether the HMS SDK code is obfuscated in the configuration file. For details about how to modify the configuration file, visit https://developer.huawei.com/ consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-preparation#h1-1574846682104

Error prompt when I select the mainland.

Comment: Hi Ashan, Are you getting an error in the portal when you select mainland or an error in the app.What error are you getting? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi Zinna, When I select mainland integration check fails but the app works fine.

Comment: Hi Ashan, when you select mainland, integration check fails. But it does not give error details. Could you please provide screen shot, error message - some more details?

Comment: Hi Zinna, I attached the error image to my description.

Comment: Hi Ashan,    attached error image displays the same message asked in the post. 
Could you please attach screen shot of mainland selection page. Is it from AG portal?  Are you just getting Critical issue detected error?  Provide more error details and logs if any.

Comment: Hi Ashan, you could send those info. to developer_dtse@Futurewei.com if email works better for you.